# How do I decod node-hid data buffer from a&d scale

Tags: node.js

I have an A&D scale that I monitoring input from using node-hid. I am successfully reading the input, but I can't figure out how to decode the binary data. Any help is appreciated.

This is the code I am using:

```
var HID = require('node-hid');
var devices = HID.devices();
var device = new HID.HID('USB_0dbc_0005_14400000');

device.on("data", function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

And this is what gets spat out when the scale is at zero.

```
<Buffer 00 00 53 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 57 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 62 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 62 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 62 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 62 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 62 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 63 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 62 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 62 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 58 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 53 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
```

Comment: Doesn't the manual for the product describe the protocol?

Comment: The manual outlines the data output format like this.


CSV format
--Separates the data of A&D standard format and the unit by a comma(,).
--Outputs the unit even when the data is overloaded


[S][T][,][+][0][0][0][1][2][.][7][8][,][][][g][CR][LF]


The brackets are actually boxes in the manual. It looks like each of the boxes stands for a byte. The manual calls it a character.

Comment: I have the same problem, I don know how can view correctly the data from HID scanner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just writing the buffer up on my whiteboard and thinking freely. I found some patterns in the data and wrote code for decoding and parsing the scale data. The code is included below for anyone that might need a push in the right direction.

```
"use strict";

var HID = require('node-hid');
var device = new HID.HID('USB_0dbc_0005_14400000');
var weight = []
var count = 0

module.exports.show_devices = function(){
    console.log(devices);
}

module.exports.start_logging = function(){
    device.on("data", function(data){
        var bad_array = [
            '\u0000S\u0000\u0000',
            '\u0000W\u0000\u0000',
        ]
        if (count < 20 && count % 2 == 0 && !contains(bad_array, data.toString('utf16le'))){
            weight.push(key[data.toString('utf16le')])
        }
        if(count == 19){
            display_weight()
        }
        if(count == 23){
            count = -1
            weight = []
        }
        count++
    });
}

function display_weight(){
    console.log(weight.join(''));
}

function contains(a, obj){
    for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        if(a[i] === obj){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var key = {
    "\u0000Y\u0000\u0000" : "1",
    "\u0000Z\u0000\u0000" : "2",
    "\u0000[\u0000\u0000" : "3",
    "\u0000\\\u0000\u0000" : "4",
    "\u0000]\u0000\u0000" : "5",
    "\u0000^\u0000\u0000" : "6",
    "\u0000_\u0000\u0000" : "7",
    "\u0000`\u0000\u0000" : "8",
    "\u0000a\u0000\u0000" : "9",
    "\u0000b\u0000\u0000" : "0",
    "\u0000c\u0000\u0000" : "."
}
```

Comment: @Sean I chose to broadcast the data over a socket using socket.io.